# Azure Databricks CI/CD

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration, databricks

I am referring this [link](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/continuous-integration-continuous-delivery-databricks.html) to implement CI/CD in my Databricks environment. I have set up GitHub and synced my notebook with my branch. I have created a staging and production folder for each environment. Currently I manually Import and export my notebook from master to staging folder and ran a job.
But I have some questions -

1] How to automate build after each merge to central repository?

2] How to push latest changes to multiple environment?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this PowerShell module to import/export notebooks https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/.

The basic flow is:

- Dev your notebooks as normal online
- Use Export-DatabricksFolder the notebooks to your local disk and commit to repo
- CI build runs and deploys using the Import-DatabricksFolder command

As you have used the GitHub integration you can skip the Export.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, using:

```
databricks fs cp etl-2.1-assembly.jar dbfs:/alice/etl/etl-2.1-assembly.jar
```

enables you to build the jar in a local or continuous delivery environment, then upload the jar to databricks.

This way the build is "hot" and you don't actually need to push it anywhere, but upload the tested jar to Staging/Production.